# Google map. finding shortest path

Tags: dictionary, shortest-path

Im having scenario like.
one place to another place route
if the user in way of that route
we have to fine the which one is shortest path.
Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one is answered for this question. And finally i got the solution of my own :D

let me tell you!! while creating direction service all the bounds will be stored in "path". so using this array. draw poly-lines then using geometry function "isLocationOnEdge" your_point ,poly-lines array it will return true or false (that's it :D) don't forget to add the degree..! default degree is 10e-10 so change it to 10e-2 or something.

```
      var request = {
        origin: document.getElementById("from").value,
        destination: document.getElementById("to").value,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }

      // Make the directions request

      directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

          // Box around the overview path of the first route
          var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;


            var my_polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#black',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });

      my_polyline.setMap(map);



  var my_position=new google.maps.LatLng(12.9860932,80.1744085);


  console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(my_position, my_polyline));


      var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);
      // alert(boxes.length);


    } else {
      alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the travelling sales-man algorithm to find the shortest path.  This algorithm tells that how a salesman can travel all the different places with the total distance traveled equals to minimum from among all other routes.

Comment: can you explain it bit

Comment: http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/46828/algorithmfortrav00litt.pdf  Go through this pdf . you'll surely get your answer.

Comment: any one knows about route boxer